# Django-lean fails tests, users in both/neither groups

Tags: django, django-lean

I was trying out [django-lean](https://bitbucket.org/akoha), and I was getting weird behaviour, sometimes test or control was displayed, but sometimes both or neither were displayed (for the same request).

I ran the tests with `./manage.py test experimets` and two tests failed:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: testIntegrationWithAnonymousVisitor (experiments.tests.test_tags.ExperimentTagsTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/dev/skin/experiments/tests/test_tags.py", line 35, in testIntegrationWithAnonymousVisitor
    client_factory=lambda i: Client())
  File "/home/ubuntu/dev/skin/experiments/tests/test_tags.py", line 76, in doTestIntegration
    self.assertTrue(in_test != in_control)
AssertionError: False is not true

======================================================================
FAIL: testIntegrationWithRegisteredUser (experiments.tests.test_tags.ExperimentTagsTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/dev/skin/experiments/tests/test_tags.py", line 55, in testIntegrationWithRegisteredUser
    client_factory=create_registered_user_client)
  File "/home/ubuntu/dev/skin/experiments/tests/test_tags.py", line 76, in doTestIntegration
    self.assertTrue(in_test != in_control)
AssertionError: False is not true
```

What on earth could be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem myself.. The solution is right in the docs:

> Ensure that django.core.context_processors.request is in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings.py

This should be in your `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
      "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
      "django.core.context_processors.debug",
      "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
      "django.core.context_processors.media",
      "django.core.context_processors.static",
      "django.core.context_processors.tz",
      "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
      "django.core.context_processors.request",
  )
```

Comment: See my updated fork that works with django 1.6 and python 2.7-3.3: https://github.com/MontmereLimited/django-lean